# Is it Possible to Start x-tile in Minimized Mode under Xubuntu 16.04?

Tags: command-line, xubuntu, window-manager, autostart, minimize

I want to start X-tile 2.5 in minimized mode, just to have its minimized tile shaped button available when needed.

I have created a starter containing the command

```
x-tile w
```

In doing so, a file

```
/home/user/.config/autostart/x-tile w.desktop
```

was created. It works to start x-tile after logging into my computer. But I always see me close the main window of x-tile as my first action because there are no other windows to arrange immediately after starting the computer.

**I just need the icon to quickly acces x-tile when needed.** I don't want the program's window open after logging into my computer. **How can I achieve this?**

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by setting the righ option under **Bearbeiten>Voreinstellungen** (in the German version) such that it looks like this:
[image]

Probably the caption reads **Start minimized in the systm tray** in English.

Bingo